# Discord.js client.on('message', message doesn't read my channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to read a channel and give a roll only if the string is the same as in my .txt but when I send a message in the channel with the right channel Id, it didn't even send me a message in the console.

I thought it would read and continue my code but nothing happened.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
  ],
});
const validStringsPath = 'valid_strings.txt';

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.channel.id === '1144023627419897937') {
    // Remplacez YOUR_CHANNEL_ID par l'ID de votre canal
    const content = message.content;
    // Charger les chaînes de caractères valides depuis le fichier texte
    let validStrings = fs
      .readFileSync(validStringsPath, 'utf8')
      .split('\n')
      .map((str) => str.trim());

    if (validStrings.includes(content)) {
      const role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(
        (role) => role.name === 'reseller',
      ); // Remplacez 'Nom du rôle' par le nom du rôle à attribuer
      if (role) {
        await message.member.roles.add(role);

        // Retirer la chaîne de caractères utilisée du fichier texte
        validStrings = validStrings.filter((str) => str !== content);
        fs.writeFileSync(validStringsPath, validStrings.join('\n'));

        console.log(`Attributed role and removed string: ${content}`);
      } else {
        message.channel.send("Le rôle spécifié n'existe pas sur ce serveur.");
      }

      // Supprimer le message de l'utilisateur
      message.delete().catch(console.error);
    } else {
      // Envoyer un message en message privé en cas d'échec
      message.author.send('Wrong key');

      // Supprimer le message de l'utilisateur
      message.delete().catch(console.error);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: please provide your codes and edit title more clear

Comment: As I mention in my linked answer, make sure to use the `messageCreate` event instead of `message`.